# Convert rows to columns using pivots

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like this :

```html
col1      col2
   00001      21
   00001      12
   00001      34 
   00001      36
   00001      25
   00002      32
   00002      45
   00002      64
   00002      88
   00002      21
   .....

to 
   
   000001     21  12 34  36  25
   000002     32  45 64  88  21
....
```

I know  it can be settled with pivots but i can't manage to build  the correct query

any thoughts please ?

Comment: How would you decide which value goes in which of the 5 new fields? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples in SO... As Hart CO mentioned did you tried anything on this regard?

Posting my query for your reference

```
;with cte as (
select *, RowN = Row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) from #yourtable )
select * from cte
pivot (max(col2) for RowN in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as p
```

For dynamic list of columns you can change accordingly